# My jQuery function is loads an HTML, but that HTML does not load a different jQuery selector from a different function (from flowplayer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jQuery function is loads an HTML, but that HTML does not load a different jQuery selector from a different function (from flowplayer)

```
flowplayer("player", {src: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", cachebusting: true, wmode: "transparent"});
   $('#options li a').click( function (evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#options li').removeClass('current');
         $(this).parent('li').addClass('current');
    var rackVideo = $(this).attr('href'); //JQUERY PULLS INFO FROM LINK
    var rackOutput =
        '<a href="http://c3426439.r39.cf0.rackcdn.com/pritchett/'+     rackVideo +'" id="player" style="display:block;width:348x;height:216px; display:block;">'+
        '<img src="http://www.p2ortho.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/intro-thumb.jpg" alt="Introduction Video" title="Introduction Video" width="348" height="216" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-620" />'+
        '</a>';
    $('#slidedata').html(rackOutput);
});
```

id="player" in the html that is an output is suppose to call the flowplayer function, which is not working. What am I doing wrong? anyhelp thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. What error do you see?

Answer (score 2):

The following line...

```
flowplayer("player", {src: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", cachebusting: true, wmode: "transparent"});
```

...must appear right AFTER this line:

```
$('#slidedata').html(rackOutput);
```

Why? Because it is when the `id="player"` element exists in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a link to this page or setup a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It's hard to know exactly what's going wrong without seeing the full html that your javascript is running in. I don't see anything obviously wrong, but I can't help without seeing the complete page.